# How does one override the __setitem__ method for (possibly multidimensional) arrays created via ctypes _fields_?

Tags: python, ctypes

I am using ctypes in Python 3.2.2 to encapsulate some C data structures. The ultimate goal is to be able to have an object that wraps a C structure notice when the structure's data 
contents have been modified.

Representative code:

```
from ctypes import *

class Comm(Structure):
    def __init__(self):
        self.attributes_updated = False

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        super(Comm, self).__setattr__('attributes_updated', True)
        super(Comm, self).__setattr__(name, value)


class MyCStruct(Comm):
    _fields_ = [('number', c_int),
                ('array', c_int*5)]

    def __init__(self):
        Comm.__init__(self)
```

This works great for any simple data attribute like 'number'.

```
>>> s = MyCStruct()
>>> s.attributes_updated
False
>>> s.value = 123
>>> s.attributes_updated
True
```

Since `__setattr__` is not invoked for accesses via index notation to the
`array` attribute, I would thus like to override the `__setitem__` attribute for those members of the C struct that are arrays.  Presumably, at that point I would need to include a reference back to the containing object so that the containing object's `attributes_updated` variable could be changed, but I've not gotten to the point where I am able to trap accesses to array attributes in the convenient way that I can trap accesses to simple attributes.  Is there a way to do this on the indexable objects that ctypes creates via the `_fields_` variable?  Is it possible to override `__setitem__` on `s.array`?  Might there be a better way to go about doing this?

Ideally, this would happen:

```
>>> s = MyCStruct()
>>> s.attributes_updated
False
>>> s.array[2] = 456
>>> s.attributes_updated
True
```

Edit for follow-up question:

How about a multidimensional array?

```
class MyCStruct(Comm):
    _fields_ = [('number', c_int),
                ('array', (c_int*5)*2]
```

I mistakenly expected the answer below, which works brilliantly for single dimensional arrays to do the same for arbitrarily nested ones.  There should be a way to recursively spawn proxy objects to do the same thing for arrays with more than one dimension, yes?  The syntax escapes me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a nice solution would be to return a proxy object instead of the array, which can then handle the access to the array. Could be something like this:

```
from ctypes import *

class ArrayProxy(object):
    def __init__(self, array, struct):
        self.array = array
        self.struct = struct

    def __setitem__(self, i, val):
        self.array[i] = val
        self.struct.attributes_updated = True

    def __getitem__(self, i):
        item = self.array[i]
        if issubclass(type(item), Array):
            # handle multidimensional arrays
            return ArrayProxy(item, self.struct)
        return item

class Comm(Structure):
    def __init__(self):
        self.attributes_updated = False

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        super(Comm, self).__setattr__('attributes_updated', True)
        super(Comm, self).__setattr__(name, value)

    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        attr = super(Comm, self).__getattribute__(name)
        if issubclass(type(attr), Array):
            return ArrayProxy(attr, self)
        return attr


class MyCStruct(Comm):
    _fields_ = [('number', c_int),
                ('array', c_int*5),
                ('multiarray', c_int*2*1),]

    def __init__(self):
        Comm.__init__(self)

s = MyCStruct()
print s.array
# <__main__.ArrayProxy object at 0x1b1f3d0> 
print s.attributes_updated
# False
s.array[0] = 1
print s.attributes_updated
# True

s2 = MyCStruct()
s2.multiarray[0][0] = 1
print s2.attributes_updated
# True
```

Comment: Any ideas on allowing the same type of update notification for multidimensional arrays in the C structure?

Comment: Acutally, I have :) - when returning the item in the array, i it's another array, return another proxy. updated my answer.